# Wordpress WooCommerce Bookings and Visual Composer capatibility issues

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, visual-composer, woocommerce-bookings

The Visual Composer backend editor keeps loading when WooCommerce Bookings is activated. I guess there might be the compatibility issues.

Current version installed on my website:

- Wordpress: 4.6.1
- WooCommerce Bookings: 1.9.13
- Visual Composer: 5.0

I also tried to update Wordpress and Plugins to latest version but I got the same error.

However, the Wordpress and plugins works fine on my localhost MAMP.

Should it be the settings on server?

Comment: If you go in backend **`WooCommerce > System status`** what do you get as information for both installations… Just try to see the differences between your local server and your online server. **May be you will be obliged to change of hosting** to get this plugin combination working fine… Also this could come from your theme, so check also if you get some errors in your browser DEV Tool's console.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this method works!

Comment: So this is a server / hosting issue and is not really the right place for this kind of questions / answers. If you want you can ▵ [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3730754/loictheaztec?tab=answers&sort=newest) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After I enabled SoapClient and Multibyte String on WHM for cPanel, the visual composer is working fine now. Thanks for the advise.

[image]